# Angular2 Router : navigate by route name instead of url pattern

Tags: angular

I'm looking for a way to navigate to the routes of my application by using names, like Angular UI Router does.

For example :

`const routes = [
    { path: '/detail/:id', name: 'userDetail', component: DetailComponent }
]`

`<a [routerLink]=['userDetail', {id: user.id}]>Detail</a>`

instead of :

`<a [routerLink]=['/detail', user.id]>Detail</a>`

In that way if I'd like to change the path from /detail/:id to /user/:id, I only would have to edit my routing configuration file, instead of editing all templates containing the link to my detail route.

Is it possible ?

Thanks,
V.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieved it in angular 4, I would assume it would work the same in 2.

```
<button class='button' routerLink='"acquisition" + {{someValue}}'>
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit plz?

Comment: Sorry, "acquistion" being a route defined in my app.router and somevalue just being a querystring